# Deploy spring boot war to openshift online

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, openshift

I followed this link to install simple spring boot project into openshift online. However, I couldn't get it working.

http://www.sothawo.com/2015/09/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-running-with-java8-on-openshift2/

Here is my project structure and the exception i'm seeing when I do `git push`

```
git push
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.82 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Stopping DIY cartridge
remote: CLIENT_RESULT: Application is already stopped
remote: Repairing links for 1 deployments
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit 8e5a152
remote: [ERROR] Error executing Maven.
remote: [ERROR] The specified user settings file does not exist: /var/lib/openshift/580abfc589f5cf2be2000061/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/settings.xml
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute action hook 'build' for 580abfc589f5cf2be2000061 application pointingpoker
remote: 
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Yes, target folder is red in color. I have modified the build script to below and I'm seeing this exception deploying to openshift. I thought the build script has been modified to point to java8 but I still its using 1.7

```
# call our own mvn script with the right settings
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
mvn package -X .openshift/settings.xml -DskipTests=true
```

> Console Exceptions

```
 git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 509 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Stopping DIY cartridge
remote: CLIENT_RESULT: Application is already stopped
remote: Repairing links for 1 deployments
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit f5f3e76
remote: Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232336; 2012-12-18 14:36:37-0500)
remote: Maven home: /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4
remote: Java version: 1.7.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
remote: Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111/jre
remote: Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
remote: OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
remote: [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
remote: [DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4/conf/settings.xml
remote: [DEBUG] Reading user settings from /var/lib/openshift/580abfc589f5cf2be2000061/.m2/settings.xml
remote: [DEBUG] Using local repository at /var/lib/openshift/580abfc589f5cf2be2000061/.m2/repository
remote: [ERROR] Could not create local repository at /var/lib/openshift/580abfc589f5cf2be2000061/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]
remote: org.apache.maven.repository.LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException: Could not create local repository at /var/lib/openshift/580abfc589f5cf2be2000061/.m2/repository
remote:         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.validateLocalRepository(DefaultMaven.java:504)
remote:         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:196)
remote:         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
remote:         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
remote:         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
remote:         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
remote:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
remote:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
remote:         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
remote:         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
remote:         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
remote:         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
remote:         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
remote:         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
remote: [ERROR] 
remote: [ERROR] 
remote: [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute action hook 'build' for 580abfc589f5cf2be2000061 application pointingpoker
remote: 
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the screen shot of your file structure, you have a leading `.` (dot) before `settings.xml`. It would appear that that may be causing your issue

Comment: Darn, that would've been so perfect! Did you end up with the same error message again, or different??

Comment: `remote: Deployment id is a22a5284
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting DIY cartridge
remote: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/*.jar
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success` That's the error i'm seeing.  Link to the cloud `http://pointingpoker-agilepoker.rhcloud.com/`

Comment: It's hard to tell from your screenshot, but is the `target` folder red? Perhaps that could indicate a problem. Could you post another screenshot with `target` expanded?

Comment: On the same note,  why am I seeing `Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.` I tried restarting the server multiple times from the dashboard